# How can I hide the badge on the tab when the value is zero in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, badge

My code:

```
<ion-tab title="Profile" icon="ion-ios-person-outline" badge="badge" href="#/app/profile">
  <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

The value of the badge is assigned dynamically, but when it is zero the badge is still shown. How can I hide it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value to `null` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Dexter, thank you it works !

Answer (score 4):

Setting the value to `null` hides the badge.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't pass null for empty list. Another options is to add the following:

```
<h1 matBadge="11" [matBadgeHidden]="!visible">
  Email
</h1>
```

OR

```
<h1 [matBadge]="list.length" [matBadgeHidden]="list.length===0">
  Email
</h1>
```

[documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/overview)